# Which intent flag do I need to use so that When When I press back I don't see that activity again?

Tags: android

I have an activity that leads to another. i want to make it so that the first activity never opens again once it directs to the other one

clear_top doesnt work. which flag is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will start a activity with new information and no history

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
MainActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

For your Reference, you can read android documentation : [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `android:noHistory="true"` for the first activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. No need for intent flags.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Answer (score 0):

```
i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `finish()` in your first `Activity` after your call to `startActivity(...)`.